# How to handle removed data from state

Tags: scala, session, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a `sessionization` use case. I keep my sessions `in-memory` thanks to `mapWithstate()` and update them for each incoming log. When a session ends, signaled with a specific log, I want to retrieve it and remove it from my `State`.

The problem I stumble upon is that I cannot retrieve AND remove (`remove()`) my session at the end of each `batch`, because retrieval happens outside the `updateFunction()` and the removal within it, i.e. once removed the session cannot be retrieved, and if a session ends, there should not be anymore logs for it, no more `key`s.

I can still retrieve my ended sessions but the number of "dead" sessions will escalate, thus creating an integral anomaly ("`State`-overflow") that if left unchecked will threaten the system itself. This solution is not acceptable.

As it seems like a common use-case, I was wondering if anyone had come up with a solution?

---

**EDIT**

Sample code below:

```
def mapWithStateContainer(iResultParsing: DStream[(String, SessionEvent)]) = {
  val lStateSpec = StateSpec.function(stateUpdateFunction _).timeout(Seconds(TIMEOUT)

  val lResultMapWithState: DStream[(String, Session)] = 
        iResultParsing.mapWithState(lStateSpec).stateSnapshots()

  val lClosedSession: DStream[(String, Session)] = 
        lResultMapWithState.filter(_._2.mTimeout)

    //ideally remove here lClosedSession from the state
}

private def stateUpdateFunction(iKey: String,
                                iValue: Option[SessionEvent],
                                iState: State[Session]): Option[(String, Session)] = {
  var lResult = None: Option[(String, Session)]

  if (iState.isTimingOut()) {
    val lClosedSession = iState.get()
    lClosedSession.mTimeout = true

    lResult = Some(iKey, lClosedSession)
  } else if (iState.exists) {
      val lUpdatedSession = updateSession(lCurrentSession, iValue)
      iState.update(lUpdatedSession)

      lResult = Some(iKey, lUpdatedSession)

      // we wish to remove the lUpdatedSession from the state once retrieved with lResult
      /*if (lUpdatedSession.mTimeout) {
         iState.remove()
         lResult = None
       }*/
    } else {
       val lInitialState = initSession(iValue)
       iState.update(lInitialState)

       lResult = Some(iKey, lInitialState)
    }

    lResult
}

private def updateSession(iCurrentSession: Session, 
                          iNewData: Option[SessionEvent]): Session = {
    //user disconnects manually
    if (iNewData.get.mDisconnection) {
        iCurrentSession.mTimeout = true
    }

    iCurrentSession
}
```

Comment: *The problem I stumble upon is that I cannot retrieve AND remove (remove()) my session at the end of each batch, because retrieval happens outside the updateFunction() and the removal within it,* Can you show a code example that illustrates what that means? What do you mean by "access is outside the update function"?

Comment: Code edited. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Definitely. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `MapWithStateRDD.stateSnapshot`, you can return the updated state as the *return value* of your `mapWithState` operation. This way, the finalized state is always available outside the your stateful DStream.

This means that you can do:

```
else if (iState.exists) {
  val lUpdatedSession = updateSession(lCurrentSession, iValue)
  iState.update(lUpdatedSession)

  if (lUpdatedSession.mTimeout) {
    iState.remove()
  }

  Some(iKey, lUpdatedSession)
}
```

And now change your graph to:

```
val lResultMapWithState = iResultParsing
                            .mapWithState(lStateSpec)
                            .filter { case (_, session) => session.mTimeout }
```

What happens is now that the state is being removed *internally*, but because you're returning it from your `StateSpec` function, it's available to you outside for further processing.